# Xpath expression with breaks in the middle

Tags: xpath

I have the following code

```
<tr>
 <td>
  F10_12-03_R1200
  <br/>
  v01.00_Vorgelegt
</td>
</tr>
```

which i have to access using Xpath.
I've tried using

```
 .//tr/td[contains(text(), 'F10_12-03_R1200')]
```

Which works but also matches other nodes.
When trying

```
 .//tr/td[contains(text(), 'F10_12-03_R1200') and contains(text(), 'v01.00_Vorgelegt')]
```

nonthing is coming.

Any hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I change your XPath too:

```
.//tr/td[contains(., 'F10_12-03_R1200') and contains(., 'v01.00_Vorgelegt')]
```

It outputs the desired output in Altova XML Spy. I have tested it.

See next screenshot: http://i929.photobucket.com/albums/ad134/markdark81/xpath.png